# How to return the array variables values to another function on javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function getPassedUsers() {
  var rr = ['a', 'b'];
  var xx = ['c'];
  return { rr, xx };
}

function ABC() {
  // i want to show letter 'b'
  console.log(rr[1]);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" onClick="ABC()">
```

How to show the letter 'b' when I click the button ?

Comment: What do you mean "How to show log letter 'b' when I click the button ?"

Comment: "Show" as in "Put into the HTML document?" If so, where? Just some random location?

Comment: @RedGuy11 I want to call getPassedUsers() variable from ABC function

Comment: Did you want to _call_ `getPassedUsers()` somewhere?

Comment: [Learn some js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Return_values) maybe?

Comment: @KANZAKIRIN `getPassedUsers()` isn't a variable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for you: [free code camp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkZNo7MFNFg)

```
function getPassedUsers() {
    var rr = ["a", "b"];
    var xx = ["c"];

    return {
        rr: rr,
        xx: xx,
    };
}

function ABC() {
    var data = getPassedUsers();
    console.log(data.rr);
    console.log(data.xx);
    // you should first call `getPassedUsers` function
    // so `getPassedUsers` generate that data and return it for you
    // and you will save it in `data` var
    // if you want data from `getPassedUsers` you should call it first
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that like this.

```
function ABC(){
  const {rr} = getPassedUsers();
  console.log(rr[1]);
};
```